# Coefficients of the cohomology after applying the smash product

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $E$ be a complex oriented cohomology theory, let $p$ be a prime number and $M(p)$ be the Moore spectrum of the group $\mathbb{F}_p$. Then the cohomology theory $E \wedge M(p)$ is the cohomology theory $E$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_p$, it is defined by the spectrum whose $n$-component is $M(\mathbb{F}_p, n)$.

My question is the following: What can I say about $(E \wedge M(p))^*$ and $(E \wedge M(p))^q$? I am asking, because I want to prove the following: Suppose the kernel of $E^q \stackrel{\cdot 2}{\to} E^q$ is a finite dimensional $\mathbb{F}_2$ vector space for each $q$, then $(E \wedge M(p))^q$ is a finite $2$-group for each $q$.
My guess is that $(E \wedge M(p))^* = E^* \otimes M(p)^*$, i.e. that $(\cdot)^*$ commutes with the tensor product, but I dont know how to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is *not* true that you have a Kunneth theorem that asserts $(X \wedge Y)^* \cong X^* \otimes Y^*$.  However, for Moore spectra, which has a simple cell structure, the difference between $(E \wedge M(p))^*$ and $E^* \otimes \mathbb{F}_p$ is captured in an exact sequence of the form $$0 \to E^q \otimes \mathbb{F}_p \to (E \wedge M(p))^q \to \operatorname{Tor}(E^{q+1}, \mathbb{F}_p) \to 0.$$

The $\operatorname{Tor}$ term need not vanish, but does for example if $E^{q+1}$ is $p$-torsionfree.

This is all stated and proved in Adams' blue book, around proposition III.6.6.